# Android how to create a ticker of arraylist of news using recycler view

Tags: java, android, ticker

I need to create a ticker that scroll horizontally always like a ticker of news , i already try to create one using recycler view but it is scrolling too fast no one can read the news. How to I make it slowly? or any other method to do this?

```
 SpeedyLinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new SpeedyLinearLayoutManager(HomeActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false) {
        @Override
        public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView,RecyclerView.State state, int position) {
            LinearSmoothScroller smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(HomeActivity.this) {
                private static final float SPEED = 50f;// Change this value (default=25f)
                @Override
                protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
                    return SPEED/displayMetrics.densityDpi ;
                }

                @Override
                public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
                    return null;
                }
            };
            smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
            startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
        }

    };
    rvTicker.setAdapter(tickerAdapter);
    rvTicker.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rvTicker.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Here I'm using custom layout manager, below:

```
public class SpeedyLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

private static final float MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = 5f; //default is 25f (bigger = slower)

public SpeedyLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SpeedyLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
}

public SpeedyLinearLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

@Override
public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position) {

    final LinearSmoothScroller linearSmoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext()) {

        @Override
        public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
            return SpeedyLinearLayoutManager.this.computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
        }

        @Override
        protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
            return MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH / displayMetrics.densityDpi;
        }
    };

    linearSmoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
    startSmoothScroll(linearSmoothScroller);
}
}
```

Comment: What happens when you change `SPEED`?